# How to make spacy rule-base matchs only what is between the give pattern

Tags: nlp, spacy, matcher, information-extraction

I have the following code:

```
doc = nlp("My big pencil is red. Your pencil is green.")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("pencil", None, [
    {"LEMMA": "-PRON-"},
    {"OP": "*"},
    {"LEMMA": "pencil"},
])
matches = matcher(doc)
for (entity_key, start_token, end_token) in matches:
    print(start_token, end_token, doc[start_token:end_token])
```

When I a run it, I get:

```
0 3 My big pencil
6 8 Your pencil
0 8 My big pencil is red. Your pencil
```

However, I just want it return the matches for the start and end tokens:

```
0 3 My big pencil
6 8 Your pencil
```

Is there a way to restrict matcher to only return everything between the start and end tokens?

Answer (score 0):

The third match is a valid match for the pattern `-PRON- * pencil`.

Since the `Matcher` doesn't have an option for `*` to be non-greedy, you will need to filter the matches returned to get the results that you want.